# How to calculate sum of floating point values on Windows command prompt or Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I have a list of floating point values that I want to add together using just CMD or PowerShell.

How to do it?

Example:

```
93947922,7
77441,0
77429114,8
53747239,4
445002,6
2066,7
201257230,1
...
```

Comment: Using Powershell, just add them (my decimal separator is `.`) `93947922.7+77441.0+77429114.8+53747239.4+445002.6+2066.7+201257230.1` -> `426906017.3`

Comment: This is not how SO works. You have an answer to your original question. If that leads you to a different question, you should create a new question.

Comment: and fwiw - Powershell isn't adding numbers wrong. What you are seeing is standard floating point arithmetic. 0.1 [can't be represented](https://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/) exactly in binary.

Comment: I have rolled back the question to earlier version. The question was how to sum a bunch of values. If the results are surprising, open a new question asking about that. If you edit this question, previous answers do not make any sense anymore.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Batch files do not support floating point arithmetics. A work-around based on integer math is possible, but for most use cases it would be way too much work.

In Powershell, one needs to use a period `.` as decimal separator instead of a comma `,`, as comma is reserved to element separator. In practice, this means that

```
2066,7
```

is, for Powershell, a list of two elements, namely `2066` and `7`. So the comma needs to be switched in order to make Powershell understand that's it's about floating points.

For easy processing, first add all the elements into an array. Then loop through the array and convert each value into a double (the default floating point type). Finally, sum the elements and display the results.

```
$arr = @()
$arr += "93947922,7"
$arr += "77441,0"
$arr += "77429114,8"
$arr += "53747239,4"
$arr += "445002,6"
$arr += "2066,7"
$arr += "201257230,1"

# Convert string values into double

# Using brute force search and replace and cast
# for($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.count; ++$i) { $arr[$i] = [double]$arr[$i].Replace(',', '.') }

# If you know a culture that uses commas (European ones often do)
# Double.Parse() can use its number format too.
for($i = 0; $i -lt $arr.count; ++$i) { 
  $arr[$i] = [double]::Parse($arr[$i], [CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo("fi-FI").NumberFormat) 
}

# Sum the elements
$sum = 0
$arr | % { $sum += $_ }

$sum
# Output
426906017,3
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea Powershell expects a period, independent of locale settings.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I think the period/comma goes back all the way into .Net and C. Sure, Powershell _prints_ a double of `2.3` as `2,3` but that's just for output. Doesn't work the other way.

Comment: instead of `[double]::Parse` you can use `[decimal]::Parse()` to get a "correct" result

Answer (score -1):

Your question lacks a ton of details, so I made several assumptions.

- I assumed that your "list of values" are placed in a *text file*, so they appear one per line (as you posted them).
- I assumed that each number have *precisely one decimal digit*, as you posted them.
- I assumed that the decimal separator is a comma, as you posted them. To change to a decimal point, just change the value in `delims=,` part.

This is the .BATch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /A "int=0, frac=0"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (test.txt) do set /A int+=%%a, frac+=%%b
set /A "int+=frac/10, frac%%=10"

echo %int%,%frac%
```

**text.txt:**

```
93947922,7
77441,0
77429114,8
53747239,4
445002,6
2066,7
201257230,1
```

**Output:**

```
426906017,3
```